# Navigating to function and passing state to function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have two simple questions. **The first question** deals with being able to navigate to a functional screen. I have a stack of screens in App.js. In my Home screen, you can see I ask the user for location permissions and log the latitude and longitude. I would like to be able to navigate from my Home screen to Screen1. You can see below how I am attempting to do so, I can do it with components but I am confused how to do it with functions.

**My second question** is dealing with the latitude and longitude states. I would like to access those values on Screen1. How can I pass those states to screen1 to be able to display them?

Here is the code below as well as a working snack demo [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@priedejm/passing-state-through-functions).

I appreciate any insight more than you know. Thank you.

EDIT:: [image]

App.js

```
export default function MyTabs() {
  return (
<NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator
     initialRouteName="Home">        
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component= {Home} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
       <Stack.Screen name="Screen1" component= {Screen1} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
    </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
);
}
```

Home.js

```
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>{latitude}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>{longitude}</Text>

      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Screen1')}>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>Click me to go to screen1</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      
    </View>
  );
}
```

Screen1.js

```
export default function Screen1() {
  const [latitude, setLatitude] = useState(null);
  const [longitude, setLongitude] = useState(null);
  
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>{latitude}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>{longitude}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with your code here is that you're not destructuring the `navigation` property in your functional component, therefore the `navigation.navigate('Screen1')` action in your `Home` component will not do anything.

The other problem is that the latitude and longitude states are only in the `Home` component, so they won't be able to be accessed from the `Screen1` component either. If you want these values passed to both components, you should move the state up into the `MyTabs` component. After moving the state up, you'll then need to pass the states as `props` to each component, while also passing the Stack Navigator built-in props. Here's an example:

```
<Stack.Screen name="Home" component={(props) => <Home {...props} latitude={latitude} longitude={longitude} />} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
```

Since you're now passing the props in the Stack Screen, you'll also need to destructure them in the child components like so:

```
export default function Home({ navigation, latitude, longitude }) {
// ... code
```

I modified your snack project, you can see my working example here: https://snack.expo.dev/DTysd-eVa

To provide some additional insight and learns for you:

Make sure you take some time to understand the basic React principles of states and props. If you ever want to access a state from one component in another component that isn't a direct child, you should *always* move the state up to the component that is a parent of both of them, and then pass the state down as props to each one. If you ever find yourself realizing that you want to access a state from a component's sibling, you should reconsider your logic and move the state upward.

Another awesome tool in React are Context Providers. If you aren't familiar with these, you should definitely check them out. Context Providers can be used to share values with components anywhere in your app so that you don't have to worry as much about component hierarchy and passing down states as props, etc. But in your particular situation, passing down a state as props is the most logical solution.

Comment: I forgot about the concept of lifting the state up. Thank you. Quick question, if Screen1 was a component rather than a function, how would you access those states within screen1.js?

Comment: @JustinPriede Do you mean if it was a `class` component rather than a functional component? Even as a class component, the concept is still the same. The state would be passed down as props and then you'd access it via `this.props.latitude` / `this.props.longitude` :-) edit: Same for the navigator, you'd access it with `this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen')`

Comment: Do you mind looking at the warning it is giving me since added the code you gave me? I added a picture of it above

Comment: I also updated my snack to match yours but with a component for Screen1, the way I am calling it with this.props is not seem to be rendering anything.

Comment: @JustinPriede I made a new snack for you where you should no longer get the warning. Instead of having the component in the `component` property of the Stack.Screen, I moved it into the component as a child function. Also, on my end I can see the latitude and longitude on the Screen1 component just fine. Here's the new snack: https://snack.expo.dev/FejE49Ydk